# Why does this for loop log letters instead of numbers?

Tags: javascript

The var is set to an integer and as far as I know `i++` means incrementing by 1. I do not understand why it prints all the characters of the variable `sentence` instead of all the integer that would correspond to the length.

```js
var sentence = "I love learning software development";

for (var i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
 if (sentence[i] !== " ") {
  console.log(sentence[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: String is collection of characters

Comment: `sentence[i]` means "extract the character at position `i` in the string and create a new string containing only that character"

Comment: *"...instead of all the integer that would correspond to the length"* What do you mean? Do you expect: `[0, 1, 2, 3...]`?

Comment: Please give an example of what you *want* the program to print.  What are you *expecting*?  How does what it *does* do differ from what you expect, or are trying to make it do?

Answer (score 2):

String [Character access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)

> There are two ways to access an individual character in a string. The first is the `charAt()` method:

```
return 'cat'.charAt(1); // returns "a"
```

> The other way (introduced in ECMAScript 5) is to treat the string as an ***array-like*** object, where individual characters correspond to a numerical index:

```
return 'cat'[1]; // returns "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `var sentence = "..."` creates a collection or array of characters that you are then looping over.

A minor change in your code to help explain.

```js
// Create a string (or an array of characters)
var sentence = "I love learning software development";

// Loop over the length of `sentence`.
// `i` is the index in the array from 0 to `sentence.length`
for (var i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  if (sentence[i] !== " ") {
    console.log("char:["+ sentence[i] +"] i:["+ i +"]");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear.
Do you want to print the index of every character that does *not* correspond to as space ("")?
If so, below would do that.

```js
var sentence = "I love learning software development";

for (var i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
 if (sentence[i] !== " ") {
  console.log(i);
 }
}
```

In the above code, I am printing the index, `i`, as long as the value at that index (`i`) is not a space character.  Your code `sentence[i]` tells it to print the value at the index (i), which would be the character at that location in the string.

On the other hand if you want the Ascii value at index `i`, you need to use the `charAt` function: `sentence.charAt[i]`.

```js
var sentence = "I love learning software development";

for (var i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
 if (sentence[i] !== " ") {
  console.log(sentence.charCodeAt(i));
 }
}
```

As another comment suggested, "...instead of all the integer that would correspond to the length" is unclear.
There is only 1 `length` for any given string. This is also true for any array at in any particular point in time.
Perhaps you mean *index*?
Each character has a unique index in any particular string.

To answer your question from the comments below:

```
index:     0    1    2 3 4 5    6    7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
sentence:  I (space) l o v e (space) l e a  r  n  i  n g software development
```

There are a total of 36 characters in the sentence. (If I counted correctly)
index values start at 0 and end at 35
length is 36.  But remember the last index number is 35, and the first is 0.

```js
var sentence = "I love learning software development";

for (var i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    console.log("index:", i, "character:", sentence.charAt(i));
}
console.log ("\nlength: ", sentence.length, "index 0 - ", sentence.length-1);
```

Comment: 1=a, 2=b, 3=c...

Is this the index you are talking about?

Sorry I am very new.

Comment: @TuCraiN Index is the location in the string.  If you write 0 above the first letter in the string, then the 2nd letter in the string is 2, etc, count each letter in the string, the `index` is the number, or location of each letter in the string.  Arrays and Strings in JS (and *most* languages start at 0, not 1).  So in your loop, i is the index.  You are looping through every "letter location" in the string, and printing out the letter at that index. Unless the "letter" is a space, because your 'if` statement tells JS to skip over spaces.  The question is, what do *you* want it to print.

Comment: You might need to read up on strings and arrays. We cannot give a complete tutorial and explanation of the JavaScript language on this site.  Sorry, this is just not the proper format, or purpose, of this particular site.  Hopefully this can point you in the right direction.  When you have a little better clarity, come back to revisit this question, and perhaps we can help you more.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp  Also, I'm going to add another snippet that will print the index, and the character at that index of the string.  Hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: index (i) is corresponds to the sequence of letters in the sentence. i= 0th place, the 1st place, the 2nd place, the 3rd place... *in the given sentence*. An *index* (`i` in your code) is a *location*, kind of like counting.  But unlike "normal life", it starts at `0` instead of `1`. There *is* a such thing as "a" represented by a particular number, "b" always represented by a different number, etc. But In computers, the numbers are very different. They are known as ASCII values, or utf-8 values, etc. You can look those up. If this is what you want, see my 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are experienced in a different language where indexing a character of a string would return a integer.

In JavaScript, you get a human representation of the string. The string is initially encoded in UTF-16, converted into binary, and then stored in memory. However, when you access it, you get the actual string instead of UTF-16 code due to an language-specific automatic conversion.

However, if you are using Node.js you can use a buffer to store the string and deal with binary data directly.

In JavaScript, if you want to get the code you can use **codePointAt(index)** method:

```
alert( "z".codePointAt(0) ); // 122
alert( "Z".codePointAt(0) ); // 90
```